# IE: border-radius with background is not smooth

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a styling problem in IE environment. When I use border-radius to make a div circle, the border of the circle div is not smooth as chrome or firefox show.

Following are the code that I use

html

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="circle-images"></div>
</div>
```

css

Padding-top:60% makes div square when you place background image.

```
.circle-images{
   width:60%;
   padding-top:60%;
   border-radius: 60%;  
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   background: url("some/path/to/jpg") no-repeat center center;
   background-size:contain;
 }
```

I also tried this style as well. The border helped a little smoother than without border but it has a lot of noises on the border.

```
.circle-images{
  width: 60%;
  padding-top:50%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  border: 27px solid #EAEAE4;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  background: url("some/path/to/jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

Is there any way make border smooth as Chrome in IE ?

** update ** 
Since @LGSon was asking sample images, here is what's happening

[IE noises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aen8E.png)

Comment: What is the Version of IE?

Comment: I use Edge but I want to support up to ie8 and emulator for ie 8 on edge also shows noises :(

Comment: I checked IE11-9, what noise are you talking about? ... Do you have an image showing it?

Comment: @LGSon I updated the description. Please refer the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in IE. The safest way (but not the easiest) is to make the images them selves circular. Another solution is to try and use browser specific hacks, but this is very unsafe.

If at all possible, I recommend converting to an image structure like PNG which allows transparency, then making your images circular.